# Player is no longer moving left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Wanted to flip the firePoint and now the player is no longer moving left.

```
void Update()
{

    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * h * movSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (h > 0 && !facingRight)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    else if (h < 0 && facingRight)
    {
        Flip();
    }

}

private void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: `Transform.Translate` has a second parameter, which defaults to `Space.Self` So if you flip an object with -1, in direction, flipping it is essentially making that -1 a 1, so when flipped he will continue to move right instead of left.  So use the second parameter with space.world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Transform.Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) moves in a coordinate space *relative to the object* if you don't use its second parameter.  Since you're flipping it, you're always moving the same direction.  The linked documentation states:

> If `relativeTo` is left out or set to `Space.Self` the movement is applied
>   relative to the transform's local axes.

You want to use [`Space.World`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.World.html) as the second argument (default is [`Space.Self`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.Self.html)):

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.right * h * movSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @EmphaticAxis If this works for you, don't forget to approve the answer so the question is marked as solved ;D